# VBA Excel Concatenate & Hyperlink trouble

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink, concatenation

```
Sub Panel_HyperLink()


'Set Ranges'
Dim oTarget As Range
Dim oDest As Range
Dim oBehind As Range
Dim oAhead As Range
Dim oCell As Range


'Set up target fiels to check & destination of information will go'
Set oDest = ActiveSheet.Range("A2")
Set oTarget = ActiveSheet.Range("B1:BBB1")

For Each oCell In oTarget
    Set oBehind = oCell.Offset(0, -1)
    If oCell.Value <> "" And oBehind = "" Then
        Set otext = oCell
        oDest.Value = otext
        Set oAhead = oCell.Offset(0, 1)
        While oAhead <> ""
            Set otext = otext + oAhead
            Set oAhead = oAhead.Offset(0, 1)
        Wend
        oDest.Value = otext
        oDest = Hyperlinks.Add(oCell, oDest, , , "Link")
        oDest = oDest.Offset(1, 0)
    End If
Next oCell

End Sub
```

In my 'While' Loop, I am unable to concatenate 'oAhead' to 'otext'. This gives me a "Type Mismatch Error".

An error also prompts when I try to Hyperlink 'oDest' to the current 'oCell'.

Answer (score 0):

A cell is an object; you need to look at the cell's value property to get the text:

```
For Each oCell In oTarget
    Set oBehind = oCell.Offset(0, -1)
    If oCell.Value <> "" And oBehind = "" Then
        Set otext = oCell.Value
        oDest.Value = otext
        Set oAhead = oCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
        While oAhead <> ""
            Set otext = otext + oAhead
            Set oAhead = oAhead.Offset(0, 1)
        Wend
        oDest.Value = otext
        oDest = Hyperlinks.Add(oCell, oDest, , , "Link")
        oDest = oDest.Offset(1, 0)
    End If
Next oCell
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't declared `oText` (and you're using the `Set` keyword) it's being handled like a range object. So in your while loop, you're telling a range to concatenate with another range.

Try making these changes:

```
'Add this:
Dim oText As String

'Change this:
Set otext = oCell
'To this:
oText = oCell

'And finally, change this:
Set otext = otext & oAhead
'To this:
oText = oText & oAhead
```